# Find common elements using Pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am a newbie to the world of Hadoop,Currently I am exploring with Pig scripts. I have to write a pig scripts which finds out common data between 2 files.

For Instanace,

**SampleFileA** has data:

1,A,,M

2,B,25,F

the above data describes column 1 as **ID**, Column 2 as **Name**,Column 3 as **Age** and Column 4 as **Gender**

**SampleFileB** has same data:

1,A,,M

2,B,25,F

I tried various joins but am not getting the expected output because of a blank or null present in column 3 of the first record.

**the expected output is:**

**(2,B,25,F),(2,B,25,F)
(1,A,,M),(1,A,,M)**

But what I am getting is:

**(2,B,25,F),(2,B,25,F),
,(1,A,,M)**

I am not sure where that empty data is coming from in the output.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your Pig script?

Comment: The reason your script isn't returning the first record is because they aren't the same.  `1,A,,M` doesn't necessarily = `1,A,,M` from another file.  They both missing age records but the record they are missing *could* be different (unless `age` doesn't change and `id` is unique, then just `JOIN` by `id`)